# Is there a way to calculate $\lambda$ guaranteeing a unique solution to $\sin(10x)\sin(x^2) = \lambda$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

If $ f(x) = \sin(10x)\sin(x^2) $ (depicted below) is a function with real arguments and $ \lambda $ is a (real) constant, then is there a way to **calculate** $ \lambda $ that guarantees the existence of a **unique solution x** for $ f(x) = \sin(10x)\sin(x^2) = \lambda $ ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE! Take a [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). You will find that simple questions that don't provide any context are poorly received. You can add some context (what you understand about the problem, what progress you have made so far, what is your level, etc.) That will help us answer your question correctly and guide you through the process. To do so, you can [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4426045/edit) your post. Consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Because the function is continuous and oscillating, then such a $\lambda$ must be a maximum or minimum of the function.  Does such a value exist? I don't know.  But calculus can at least help with finding local extrema.